# Non-parametric alternative to two-way ANOVA using SPSS?

Tags: anova, spss, nonparametric

I would like to test for the **interaction** effect of **2** independent **categorical** variables on 1 dependent **continuous** variable using **SPSS**. Unfortunately, I do not have equal sample sizes; the residuals are not normally distributed; Levene's test is significant too. What test can I use?

I have run an ANOVA and it shows very interesting results. Yet, I guess that with all those violations, I cannot consider them, right?

I have checked other (similar) questions, but surprisingly none of them could give me an answer. Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

SPSS doesn't have a nonparametric analogue of a 2x2 ANOVA per se, but the GENLIN procedure for generalized linear models offers modeling for variables with other than normal distributions.